# Transform a map data structure on terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm struggling with my head trying to transform (or convert) the next terraform map:

```
  clients = {
    "client1" = {
      sites = {
        site1 = {
          users = [
            "user1",
            "user2",
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "client2" = {
      sites = {
        site2 = {
          users = [
            "user3",
            "user4",
          ]
        },
        site3 = {
          users = [
            "user5",
            "user6",
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  }
```

Into something like this:

```
  sites_per_client = {
    "client1-site1" = [
      "user1",
      "user2",
    ]
    "client2-site2" = [
      "user3",
      "user4",
    ]
    "client3-site3" = [
      "user5",
      "user6",
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying several loops but I still don't feel comfortable with Terraform.
Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took a while to figure out, and is also complex enough that explaining it would be a lot, but here is the solution. Given the above structure in the question defined in `locals` as `clients`:

```
locals {
  sites_per_client_reconstruct = flatten([
    for client, client_attrs in local.clients : [
      for site, site_attrs in client_attrs.sites :
      { "${client}-${site}" = site_attrs.users }
    ]
  ])
  
  sites_per_client = { for index, client_site in local.sites_per_client_reconstruct : keys(client_site)[0] => values(client_site)[0] }
}
```

Where `local.sites_per_client` is:

```
sites_per_client    = {
  client1-site1 = [
    "user1",
    "user2",
  ]
  client2-site2 = [
    "user3",
    "user4",
  ]
  client2-site3 = [
    "user5",
    "user6",
  ]
}
```

exactly as desired.

Comment: @JosePeinado Glad to hear it. Please upvote and accept if it worked well for you.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed upvote, thanks a lot, Matt!